# How to install a i686 Arch Linux to a USB?

Tags: arch-linux, 32-bit

I am following the [Install from existing Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux) guide to install Arch Linux to a USB from a 64bit host machine which runs Arch Linux as well. I need the target installation to be 32bit as it needs to run on an older hardware.

How do I make `pacstrap` install a 32bit version of Arch Linux onto my machine?

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
sudo linux32 pacstrap /mnt base
```

If your host system has `multilibs` enabled then copy the `pacman.conf` to pacman-32.conf, comment out `multilibs` and run as

```
sudo linux32 pacstrap -C pacman-32.conf /mnt base
```